# how to open and view a PowerPointPresentation in a browser?

Tags: c#, html, internet-explorer, powerpoint

Currently, I have a link to a powerpoint file and when you click the link it opens the file in edit mode.

I have tried saving the powerpoint as a .pptv, .ppsx and a .pptx; none of these display in presentation mode. Additionally, I've added the different MIME types in IIS.

Powerpoint is installed on all computers trying to view this file, it is not installed on the server (could that be the issue).

Is there a way to programatically achieve this or is there another work around?

This is currently working in firefox but not IE8.

Comment: Is installing PowerPoint on the server an option?

Comment: i'm installing right now to see if that resolves the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be able to do this with the [Powerpoint Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) however, it requires an installed version of PowerPoint. That means you would have to install it on the server.

[Here is an example from MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303718)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a work around, but it involves editing the registry

[Opening PowerPoint Slideshows](http://joelsef.blogspot.com/2009/01/opening-powerpoint-slideshows.html)

Comment: Too bad it means changing every computers registry and currently that's impossible since it's for any user who accesses the site

Answer (score 0):

Adding response header Content-Disposition:Attachment helped me to open .ppsx files in view mode in Internet Explorer. In IIS7 follow these steps: navigate and select a folder that contains .ppsx files in left panel of IIS Manager under your web site, go to Features View, click HTTP Response Headers, add an http response header there with Name = "Content-Disposition", Value = "Attachment", click OK. Please notice that this can break another files in this folder, so it is recommended to place these .ppsx files in separate folder.